# GeoCoordinateWatcher not working in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller

**I use the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` in `C#` localhost but it does not work when it is published in Azure.**

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            string cordenadas = "";

            watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

            GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

            if (coord.IsUnknown != true)
            {
                cordenadas ="Latitud: " + coord.Latitude + ", Longitud: " + coord.Longitude;
            }
            return cordenadas;
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to do? If it worked it would presumably give you the coordinates of the server and it would never move.

Comment: @Frans I want you to not take the server's coordinates

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work like that, sorry. You need to look at the JavaScript location API. It's a much bigger subject that can be covered in an SO answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GeoCoordinateWatcher.TryStart method description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks).

> Note
>   In versions of Windows prior to Windows 7, the following conditions apply:
>   All System.Device.Location objects that have constructors can be created, but the Status property will always have the value Disabled.
>   The location indicated by the Location property of Position will always be Unknown.
>   No location events will be raised.

The web app server's OS is windows NT 6.2, so we couldn't use the GeoCoordinateWatcher to get the location. The Location property of Position will always be Unknown.

I have remote debug the web app.

[image]

The web app OS:

[image]

> I want you to not take the server's coordinates

Do you mean you want to get the client's coordinates? If this is your requirement. I suggest you could try to use javascript navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method to get the client user's position.

More details, you could refer to below codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]